# How do I validate a group of textboxes by only numbers, no <> 12 and not empty in vba

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub txt_dd_sku12_beforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

''start data validation by (len), (numeric) ''

If Len(Trim(txt_dd_sku12)) <> 12 Then
    txt_dd_sku12.BackColor = RGB(116, 174, 244)
    MsgBox ("the entry must be a 12 Digit SKU only")
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNumeric(Trim(txt_dd_sku12)) Then
    MsgBox " Highlighted field can not be blank. entry DD'S Sku12  to proceed further"
    txt_dd_sku12.BackColor = RGB(116, 174, 244)
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

i have a 5 textboxes the i have to validate by, before update insert in my table when i press enter in my last textbox, but if i go back to an early textbox dont insert data until i press enter.

1. only numbers
2. not empty
3. no more or less of 12 digits

Comment: Thank you  for your help

Comment: You need to mark one as correct.  Only you can do that.  Click on the green check mark by the answer that is correct and the one which you used to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are looking for is the forms before update event.  That will keep you from moving to a new record until your individual field requirements have been met.

```
Public Function ValidField(ctl as Control, FieldLength as integer) as Boolea
    If Not IsNumeric(ctl) then
        MsgBox "Highlighted field can not be blank. Enter an appropriate text."
        ctl.backColor = RGB(116, 174, 244)
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
        Exit Function
    End if

    if len(ctl) <> FieldLength or IsNull(ctl) or ctl = "" then
        MsgBox "The entry must be a 12 digit sku only."
        ctl.BackColor = RGB(116,174,244)
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
        Exit Function
    End if

    ValidField = true 
End Function

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not ValidField(txtBox1, 7) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Curly braces? In VBA? :P

Comment: here are my fields rr_PO <>7, DD_po <>7, rr_sku <>12, DD_sku <> 12, to validate.

Comment: @FaguaHDanel Updated to show how you can check a variable length depending on which field you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If Len(Trim(txt_dd_sku12)) <> 12
```

To

```
If Len(Trim(txt_dd_sku12)) <> 12 And IsNumeric(Trim(txt_ss_sku12)) And Trim(txt_ss_sku12) <> vbNullString
```